# Gem like sendgrid-ruby for Ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sendgrid

Is there any gems like [sendgrid-ruby](https://github.com/SendGridJP/sendgrid-ruby) which can be used with Ruby 1.8.7 ? I need to schedule emails like newsletters from my application. APIs are not working for me. Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SendGrid's Gem uses 1.9.3 and above. You might consider updating to this version if you are looking to use the sendgrid ruby gem.

Comment: Upgrading the version is not a solution for me now. I build a API wrapper to use SendGrid with my application.

Comment: How about using [this 3rd party library?](https://github.com/stephenb/sendgrid/blob/master/sendgrid.gemspec) It isn't an official SendGrid library, but it looks like it uses 1.8.*

Comment: I tried to use it. But no use. My system is ancient. Rails 2.2.2 and ruby gem version 1.3.1. I think the only solution is upgradation of the system.